# How can I add data from a public method into a private member array in the same class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, class-template

I'm having trouble storing data read in from the keyboard into a private member array.

When I try to simply add the data using:

```
std::cin >> array[counter];
```

I get a long error: [pasted here to save space](https://pastebin.com/Yq7asZyD)

I'm currently trying to find a way to store the input into a temporary variable and then sending it to the array, but I get the same error.

**Header:**

```cpp
template<class Type>
class Department
{
  private:
    const static int MAX = 4;
    typedef std::string sArray[MAX];
    typedef Type tArray[MAX];

    std::string deptName;
    sArray names;
    tArray salary;

    public:
       Department(const std::string & dept);
       bool Add() const;
    ...
    ...
};
```

**Implementation:**

```cpp
template<class Type>
Department<Type> :: Department(const std::string & name)
{...}

template<class Type>
bool Department<Type> :: Add() const
{
  if (IsFull())
    return 0;
  else
  {
    Type tempName;
    Type tempSal;
    std::cout << "\nAdd called\n";
    std::cout << "Enter employee ID:\t"; std::cin >> tempName;
    std::cout << "Enter employee salary:\t"; std::cin>>tempSal;

    //What is the best way to add the data stored in tempName, and tempSal to the arrays in the class

    return 1;
  }
}
```

[Link to MCVE](https://repl.it/@mgualdarrama/prj3-v2-mvce)

Comment: I've included a link to an mcve at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Since `Add` is const you cannot edit members in the class (unless you make them mutable) - are you sure that `Add` should be `const`? (making the `Add` non const in your example runs the code btw)

Comment: Ugh, that was the problem.  I misunderstood part of the project specifications that said all methods need to be const, when in actuality it said "all accessor methods must be const", thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue came down to that the `Add` method was marked as `const`. The error message

> invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream'
>         (aka 'basic_istream') and 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string'))
>       std::cout << "Enter employee ID:\t"; std::cin >> employee[counter];

really means that the compiler cannot find any operator>> for std::istream (which is cin) that accepts a const std::string

There are two ways to solve this, which both have their advantages and disadvantages.

- You remove the `const` from `Add`. The class members are now allowed to be changed (and the employee[counter] will be a std::string instead as far as `Add` is concerned).

However, Add can change **all** of the class members.

or

- you add the [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) keyword to employee:

```
mutable sArray employee;
```

this will make sArray allowed to be changed even from `const`. However, now **all** const functions can change `employee`.